# Пропала возможность редактировать url, мета теги и добавлять изображения Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, cms

Пропала возможность редактировать url, мета теги и добавлять изображения Wordpress.
Нажимаю кнопку изменить рядом с url и ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Для редактирования тегов, url и изображения записи в редакторе WordPress (как в новом, так и в старом) используется JavaScript. 
Скорее всего, какой нибудь свежеустановленный плагин генерирует JavaScript ошибку на странице редактирования записи.
Отключите плагины, которые были установлены перед появлением проблемы и все заработает.